# Testing requests.post using Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am new to testing using Pytest. I have following method: I want to test get_categories method. I would like to mock the requests.post method to send the sample response and validate

```
class Process:
    _id = None
    _header = None
    _payload = None
    API_URL = os.environ["API_URL"]

    ZERO_RESPONSE = {"category": [{"p1": "0", "p2": "0"}, {
        "p1": "0", "p2": "0"}, {"p1": "0", "p2": "0"}]}

    ZERO_RESPONSE_SEGMENT = {"segments": [{"name": "na", "p": "0"}]}

    def __init__(self, inputParam) -> None:
        self._header = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        self._header_segment = {'Content-type': 'application/json;format=pandas-split',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'}
        self._payload = {'param1': 1 if inputParam.param1 else 0, 'param2': list(map(int, inputParam.param2.split(','))),
                             'param3': inputParam.param3.split(','), 'param4': inputParam.param4.split(','),
                             'param5': [], 'param6': []}
        self._id = inputParam.id
    
    def get_categories(self):
        api = "Category"
        response = requests.post(self.API_URL, data=json.dumps(
            self._payload), headers=self._header, timeout=2)
        if response.ok:
            result = json.loads(response.content)
            self.log_api_req_response(result, api)
            return result
        else:
            self.log_api_error(response, api)
            return self.ZERO_RESPONSE
```

I am doing as follows: I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock_request:
        mock_request.post("https://www.cat.com", json={'category':[{'p1':0.43,'p2':17},{'p1':0.41,'p2':13},{'p1':0.06,'p2':21}]})
```

Comment: You should `assertions` to make the tests complete.

Comment: I do not think this is the right way to test requests.post method

Comment: If you want to test `get_categories` for real, then you should not be using mock.